# Como desativar autocompletar automatico e mostrar documentação no eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Estou sendo obrigado a usar o eclipse por causa da faculdade,e já tentei inúmeros tutorias e nenhum resolveu os meus problemas !

O primeiro e o que mais esta me dando dor de cabeça e que quando escrevo alguns códigos eles são completados automaticamente (sem usar o atalho)

Exemplo: quando tento escrever System.out.printf assim que abro o parentes o eclipse ja completa o código com System.out.printf(format, args)

O segundo e que quando deixo o cursor do mouse sobre algum comando abre uma janela com a documentação do mesmo, e isso também me irrita um pouco pois as vezes fica difícil de editar algumas coisas.

Gostaria de saber como desativar essas coisas, pois o eclipse neon tem muitas opções.

Comment: Solução: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906137/disable-content-assist-in-eclipse

Comment: Eu ja tinha visto esse, o problema e que mostra como fazer isso no eclipse antigo, e mesmo achando essas mesmas opções e desativando todas as disponíveis continua a mesma coisa !

Comment: Tentou as sugestoes de todas as respostas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para desativar o autocomplete de parâmetros, vá no menu *Window ->Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist* e desmarque a opção *Fill method arguments and show guessed arguments*, conforme segue o print:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E para desativar a exibição do javadoc quando o mouse passar por algum método, vá em *Window ->Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Hovers* e desmarque "*Combined Hover*":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não se esqueça de clicar em *Apply* antes de clicar em *ok*.

Veja o resultado após desativar as opções acima:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Consegui desativar, obrigado ! sabe como desativar a tela preta que fica mostrando partes da documentação quando o mouse esta sobre alguma coisa ?

Comment: @Arcashaid pronto, resposta atualizada.

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou muito ! Obrigado mesmo

Comment: Isto deveria ser padrão no Eclipse, +1